# Software Update badge won't go away

Tags: ios, software-update

After upgrading to 11.1.1 both the Settings->General menu item and the sub-menu for Software Update have a (1) badge which will not go away. Selecting the Software Update menu shows the phone software is up to date.

Is there some update I'm missing, or way to clear this badge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed simply by upgrading to 11.1.2. The badge doesn’t return after re-checking for updates. It was only released in the last 24-48 hours and I upgraded to 11.1.1 pretty fast too, so pretty sure the badge was not originally showing for 11.1.2 availability.

Answer (score 1):

There is a time-consuming workaround with 50% success, meaning it removes the badge over the outside of the Settings app and the folder (if you place Settings in a folder) but keeps it inside Settings under "General" & "Software update". For me that was enough for my OCD.

Here's the steps:

1. If you are jailbroken just get a tweak, do not proceed!!!
2. Ensure the firmware you are on or want to be on is still signed - go to ipsw.me
3. Download the appropriate (still signed) firmware from ipsw.me
4. On the iPhone/iPad go to betaprofiles.com and download a tvOS profile OLDER than your current firmware/the firmware you want to stay on.
5. Install the tvOS beta profile and reboot.
6. Using iTunes, make a FULL and ENCRYPTED local backup, on your computer, using iTunes (do not forget your password! - Save it to the keychain)
7. Using iTunes, proceed to press "Restore iPhone" while holding the "Alt (PC) or Option (Mac) Key" down.
8. An iTunes window will open asking for the file to use.  Navigate to where you saved the firmware from ipsw.me and select it.
9. Proceed with the restore, and your iPhone will be wiped and the downloaded firmware will be re-installed.
10. Restore the backup you just took.
11. Enjoy no badge over Settings!

Answer (score -4):

I have that with Mail sometimes. Normally this should help: do a reset:
for older iPhones: press and hold the ON/OFF button (or the lower sound button) and the Home button, keep holding until you see the white apple logo appear. let go and let it startip.